# Why Does Using a ViewChild in ngIf Cause Console Errors?

Tags: typescript, angular

I get a bunch of console errors with the code below that say `'child in AppComponent@0:4' has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '[object Object]'`.

The problem is in the `h1` element in the `app.component`. If I take the `*ngIf` out, the console errors go away, but I get an undefined error because `child.header` hasn't been initialized yet.

The application works just fine though. Should I just ignore the console errors? Is this a bug that might be fixed in a later version. Maybe there's a better/correct way to do what I'm trying to do without receiving console errors?

Here's the app component:

app/app.component.ts

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from 'angular2/core';
import {ChildComponent}from "./child.component";

@Component({
  directives: [ChildComponent],
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1 *ngIf="child">{{child.header}}</h1>
    <child></child>`
})
export class AppComponent { 
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) child: ChildComponent;
}
```

Here's the child component:

app/child.component.ts

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector: "child",
    template: "<p>I'm the child</p>"
})

export class ChildComponent {
    public header: string = "Child Header!!";
}
```

app/main.ts just bootstraps the app:

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.35.0/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.20/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular2@2.0.0-beta.13/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>   

    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.13/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/typescript@1.8.9/lib/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.13/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.13/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    <script>
      System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript', 
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true }, 
        packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}} 
      });
      System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/BQkAVadtxZDixrJMtuud?p=preview).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular2 doesn't like binding to results of `@ViewChild()` because the result is updated by change detection and Angular produces the error mentioned when bindings change during change detection. In your case you don't need `@ViewChile()` though. You can use a template variable instead

```
template: `<h1 *ngIf="child">{{child.header}}</h1>
<child #child></child>
```

Your code of the `AppComponent` looks pretty weird anyway. How do you expect this to work? `<child>` should only be shown when it's shown?

Comment: This was just the quickest example I could come up with to show the problem. What I'm actually trying to do is use the property in a child element to add a class onto the menu of its parent. `[class.active]=child.visible`. The template variable worked. Thanks!